# Ruby: how to erase the " in the string-keys when return a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to return a hash, of which the keys are strings and the values are arrays, by adding elements into value-arrays, for example:

```
    {"Fixnum"=>[1, 8], "Hash"=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
```

But I want to erase " in the keys, like so:

```
    {Fixnum=>[1, 8], Hash=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
```

Obviously I can't simply use .delete('"') because then the " with einzeln will be gone too. I've also tried freezing the .to_s form of the elements when adding them to value-arrays, and then use .delete, but it didn't work. I also didn't find anyway to iterate or grab the keys and use .delete directly on the keys, because the keys are frozen.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Where are you getting the keys from? Are they always going to be ruby classes? Why do you want to convert your keys from string to type?

Comment: What's the purpose of it?

Answer (score 2):

The hash keys don't actually have double quotes (`"`), you see them because the keys are *strings* and ruby will show all *strings* enclosed between double quotes; so you won't be able (nor need) to remove them.

What you could do is use *symbols* instead of *strings* for the hash keys (which is pretty much Ruby best practice).

For that you could either create the hash with *symbols*, like this:

```
my_hash = {Fixnum: [1, 8], Hash: [{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
#=> {:Fixnum=>[1, 8], :Hash=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
```

If you have no control over the keys of the hash, you can convert the keys to *symbols*, like this:

```
my_hash = {"Fixnum"=>[1, 8], "Hash"=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}

Hash[my_hash.map{ |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }]
#=> {:Fixnum=>[1, 8], :Hash=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
```

Or, as [pointed out by mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958854/ruby-how-to-erase-the-in-the-string-keys-when-return-a-hash/44958971?noredirect=1#comment76893858_44958971), you could use `Fixnum` and `Hash` classes as keys, like so:

```
my_hash = {Fixnum => [1, 8], Hash => [{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
#=> {Fixnum=>[1, 8], Hash=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
```

Again, if you don't have control over the keys of the hash, you can convert the keys to their classes, like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
my_hash = {"Fixnum"=>[1, 8], "Hash"=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}

Hash[my_hash.map{ |k, v| [eval(k.to_s), v] }]
#=> {Fixnum=>[1, 8], Hash=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}
```

<sup>1</sup> *Keep in mind that using `eval` is only recommended when you have complete trust/control over the values passed to it.*

Comment: Why not use the classes themselves as the keys? `{Fixnum=>[1, 8], Hash=>[{7=>"einzeln", 5=>[13]}]}` is a perfectly good hash.

Comment: @muistooshort Ohh, you're right! That never crossed my mind. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you. That's a great idea

Comment: You could grab `constantize` out of ActiveSupport if you wanted to avoid `eval`, or adapt the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/48b37f127fb44b787ae6c0710982d7949b14454f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L258) if you only wanted to cherry pick just that one small thing.

Comment: @muistooshort Didn't knew about `constantize`, looks good and i would prefer it over `eval`, or better yet, as you suggested, adapt its implementation (and avoid loading `ActiveSupport`). Thanks again!